# Get voice amplitude from SFSpeechRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, sfspeechrecognizer

Im using this library https://github.com/appcoda/SpeechToTextDemo to transcript voice to text

I want to have the real voice amplitude to show graph of voice with this library https://github.com/alankarmisra/SwiftSiriWaveformView

i dont know how to get this value from the first library

Comment: did you get any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can get that from Speech kit but I made something similar where I combined speech recogniser and `AVAudioRecorder` and got the `self.audioRecorder?.averagePower` which I used to update amplitude of that sound wave.