# How to generate waveform for AVSpeechSynthesizer audio?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, avaudioplayer, avspeechsynthesizer

I am trying to use Apple's inbuilt `TextToVoice`  i.e., `AVSpeechSynthesizer`

I am trying the following to draw the waveform based on audio file using `AVAudio`

var scale = 0.0
        if (avAudio?.isPlaying)!
        {
            avAudio?.updateMeters()
            var power = 0.0

```
        for x in 0..<avAudio!.numberOfChannels {
            power += Double(exactly: (avAudio?.averagePower(forChannel: x))!)!
        }
        power /= Double((SoundEffect?.numberOfChannels)!)
        scale = Double(powf(10, (Float(0.05 * power))))

        if power == -120
        {
            return
        }
        if(lastScale<scale){
            if scale>0.44{
                scale = 0.45
            }
            animateView.AnimateBar(frequency: CGFloat(scale))
        }
        lastScale = scale
    }
```

But I don't see an option to get the `averagePower` of `frequency` of the audio that is played using `AVSpeechSynthesizer`

Even `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying` returning `false`
Any solutions ?

Comment: Check this link which may help you[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906845/get-voice-amplitude-from-sfspeechrecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906845/get-voice-amplitude-from-sfspeechrecognizer)